# Kendo UI DataSource with Spring MVC model attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Spring MVC application, but I am creating the View with Kendo UI. I need to populate a table with data from model.attribute and then add a change function to the table so it is called when selection changes.
I can populate the table with data just fine, but when I select a row I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'bind' of undefined.
```

It is thrown when the code reaches this line:

```
$("#pTable").data("kendoGrid").bind("change", function() {
```

I call the Controller and add the attribute `passengers` to the model, `pTable` is the id of the table I want to use for data found in `passengers`.

My jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ include file="/include.jsp"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Airline Database</title>

<link href="../styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="../js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <kendo:splitter name="pHorSplit">
        <div id="pShow">
        <kendo:grid name="pTable" selectable="true" sortable="true" filterable="true" pageable="false">
            <kendo:grid-columns>
                <kendo:grid-column title="Passenger ID" field="passengerID"/>
                    <kendo:grid-column title="Name" field="name"/> 
                    <kendo:grid-column title="Passport" field="passport"/> 
                    <kendo:grid-column title="Email" field="email"/> 
                </kendo:grid-columns>
            <kendo:dataSource data="${passengers}"></kendo:dataSource>
        </kendo:grid>   
        </div>
        <div id="pControl">
            //...
        </div>
    </kendo:splitter>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#pTable").data("kendoGrid").bind("change", function() {
            //...
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried with defining the dataSource schema, but I got the same result.
Can anyone tell me why the data is loaded into the table but undefined at any other occassion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer, instead of using the bind method, I declared `change="onChange"` in `kendo:grid` tag, and I implemented the `onChange` method in the same jsp file.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that your call to:

```
    $("#pTable").data("kendoGrid").bind("change", function() {
        //...
    });
```

Should be placed within a handler for the document ready event:

```
$(function() {
    $("#pTable").data("kendoGrid").bind("change", function() {
        //...
    });
 });
```